# Execute a command using ProcessBuilder from windows

Tags: java, windows, process, processbuilder

I am getting the following error when i try to execute the below line from my java program on windows machine.

Could you please let me know the detailed steps to make that work?

```
final Process exec = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", query).start();
```

> error : java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: It can't find a program called bash... Can you run `bash` from a command line?

Answer (score 12):

Windows has no bash, so you have to use "CMD" (command). "bash" is being used for unix-systems.

This should work on Windows :

```
final Process exec = new ProcessBuilder("CMD", "/C", query).start();
```

if you want a nice example on how to use the ProcessBuilder in Windows : [External programs  using Java ProcessBuilder class](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-run-external-programs-by-using-java-processbuilder-class/189)

Answer (score 2):

/bin/bash doesn't exist on Windows. Try replacing /bin/bash with cmd.exe, and replacing the switch -c with /c

`final Process exec = processBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", query).start();`

Answer (score 1):

```
final Process exec = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", query).start();
```

As the error indicates, there is no executable program bash, typically bash in installed on Unix systems at location /bin/bash, so you must provide the path to your program.
Even relative paths work. This command below will work on Unix like OS with bash installed.

```
final Process exec = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", query).start();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just execute the bash command, you need the bash library for java.